# Compare Time, and set boolean If criteria is met

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to give the user an 1 hour cooldown, after submitting a video. 
So I was thinking of comparing the now Date/Time with the Date/Time(+1 hour), the video was submitted.
Then set a boolean to be true if the user has posted.

**Right now I have this:**

```
let currentTime = new Date()
let currentTimeHours = currentTime / 1000

let plusOneHour = currentTime.setHours(currentTime.getHours() + 1)

if(addedVideo == false){
  if(plusOneHour > currentTimeHours){
    user['addedDate'] = plusOneHour
    user['addedVideo'] = true
  }
  return
} else if(addedVideo == true){
  if(plusOneHour < currentTimeHours){
    user['addedVideo'] = false
  }
}
```

I really cant wrap my head around this, I would appreciate all tips!

Comment: `currentTimeHours` is actually the number of seconds. The numeric value of a Date is the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `timestamp` of the dates and add the milliseconds for one hour to the video timestamp as below:

```js
var videoDate = new Date("2017-03-03 20:00:00");
var msInHour = 1000 * 60 * 60; // ms * sec * min
var now = new Date();
var nowTime = now.getTime();
var videoTime = videoDate.getTime();
var addedVideo = (nowTime <= videoTime + msInHour);
console.log(addedVideo);
```